# GIF, Python - Side by Side

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, gif

I have two lists,

```
globalCache - [4000 of 2D Numpy Array (200,200) size].
globalCache1 - [4000 of 2D Numpy Array (200,200) size].
```

Each of those cache have 4000 2D NumPy array made up of zeros and ones.

I am trying to create an animated GIF of each of those 4000 respective images of placed side by side, so far :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

class AnimatedGif:
    def __init__(self, size=(680, 520)):
        self.fig, self.fig_axes = plt.subplots(1,2)

        self.fig.set_size_inches(size[0] / 50, size[1] / 100)

        self.fig_axes[0].set_xticks([])
        self.fig_axes[0].set_yticks([])

        self.fig_axes[1].set_xticks([])
        self.fig_axes[1].set_yticks([])

        self.images = []

    def add(self, image1,image2, label='', _stck1=-999, _stck2=-999):

       self.fig_axes[0].imshow(image1, vmin=0, cmap = 'copper', vmax=1, animated=True)
       self.fig_axes[1].imshow(image2, vmin=0, cmap = 'copper', vmax=1, animated=True)

       lbl = int(int(label)/100 * 100)
       if lbl == 0:
           lbl = ''
       self.fig_axes[0].text(-30,10, lbl, fontsize=15, color='red')
       self.fig_axes[0].text(200, 10, 'Stickiness : {0}'.format(_stck1),fontsize=12, color='red')

       self.fig_axes[1].text(-30,10, lbl, fontsize=15, color='red')
       self.fig_axes[1].text(200, 10, 'Stickiness : {0}'.format(_stck2),fontsize=12, color='red')
       self.artists.append(self.fig_axes[0].get_children())
       self.artists.append(self.fig_axes[1].get_children())

    def save(self, filename):
       animation = anim.ArtistAnimation(self.fig, self.artists)
       animation.save(filename, writer='imagemagick', fps=50)
```

But when I run this using,

```
animated_gif = AnimatedGif()

for i in range(len(globalCache)):

    animated_gif.add(globalCache1[i], 
                     globalCache[i], 
                     label=str(i), 
                     _stck1 = '1', _stck2 = '0.1')
    if i == 100 : break

animated_gif.save('ouput.gif')
```

I am getting the following output :

[image]

**Expected output was something like this (Individual GIF's were created using Python then put side by side using Online tool)** :

[image]

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Do you have the full traceback?  Also, missing a word perhaps in "I am trying to create a <ANIMATED GIF> of each of those"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Updated.

Comment: Slight ammendation, now I am able to render the GIF, but the output is not what was expected

Comment: You're adding the images one by one, so first frame will contain the left image, second frame will contain the right image, third one left again. Instead, you need to make sure each frame contains *both* images.

Comment: Is that possible in the code structure that I have right now?

Comment: Use cv2.hconcat() or np.hstack to put the two arrays side by side before saving the gif frame.

Comment: @fmw42 I did, and that works fine, its just that the final rendered GIF is around 150 mb in size, so I was trying this approach to see if the size could be reduced.

Comment: You can reduce the size of the animated gif, if you use the same common color map for all frames (and optionally use less colors than 256). This can be done using Python Wand, which is based upon and uses Imagemagick. There is a function called remap that applies the same color map to all the frames. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.7/wand/image.html and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap. The color map can be generated from color quantization of a concatenation of a number of frames. See quantize and concat at http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.7/wand/image.html.

Comment: Check your color map for your gif frames to see how may colors are include. You should only need two colors: black and white and not 256 colors. Are the red labels part of the images?